# Convert old Switch() syntax to new c# 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, switch-statement

I can't figure out how to convert this old `switch()`:

```
switch (Current)
{
    case '+':
        return new SyntaxToken(SyntaxKind.PlusToken, position++, "+", null);
    default:
        diagnostics.Add("Bad Token");
        return new SyntaxToken(SyntaxKind.BadToken, position++, text.Substring(position - 1, 1), null);
}
```

To the new syntax:

```
return Current switch
{
    '+' => new SyntaxToken(SyntaxKind.PlusToken, position++, "+", null),
    _ => new SyntaxToken(SyntaxKind.BadToken, position++, text.Substring(position - 1, 1), null),
};
```

How do i manage to get the log part in to the new syntax?

Comment: You'd have to define a function that adds to diagnostics and returns a bad syntax token and then call that in the switch arm. Blocks bodies are not valid in the new syntax. Perhaps a local function if this is the only place you'd use it

Comment: There is no old-switch vs new-switch syntax. There is a switch-statement and a switch-expression. A switch-expressions has limitations as you can see. In your case, I would probably separate logging from token creation (separation of concerns)...

Comment: @huysentruitw okay, i might try the local function that pinkfloydx33 suggested, otherwise i separate them! Maybe a switch expression isn't the best for this particular use-case! Thanks for input.. :)

Comment: Not every switch statement _should_ be converted to a switch expression. This is an example of one that shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I used a local function to solve it, don't know if it's the right solution but i'll share it anyways:

```
return Current switch
{
    '+' => new SyntaxToken(SyntaxKind.PlusToken, position++, "+", null),
     _ =>  CreateAndLogInvalid(),
};

SyntaxToken CreateAndLogInvalid() 
{
     diagnostics.Add($"ERROR: bad character input: '{Current}'");
     return new SyntaxToken(SyntaxKind.BadToken, position++, text.Substring(position - 1, 1), null);
}
```

Comment: Looks fine ... Would like to see your final code.  Might not even need a switch.  Maybe ...

Comment: @tobeypeters i have more vaild tokens to switch over, like '+', '-', '*', '/', reduced the amount of values for readablility :)

Comment: Ya, I know.  I started to offer one of a few changes.  But, without having the whole app in front of me ... case is "perfect" here.  Technically, I can reduce the above into one line of code.  But, in the one scenario, you'd need a dictionary and if nothing else would ever access this dictionary, it'd be wasteful.

Comment: Also, if CreateAndLogInvalid() isn't used anywhere else ... assume it is ... then I'd move it inside the method that calls it.  Without about knowing your code, the two lines inside that method can be put in your case '_' section.

Answer (score -1):

```
return Current switch
{
    '+' => new SyntaxToken(SyntaxKind.PlusToken, position++, "+", null),
    _ => {
        diagnostics.Add("Bad Token");
        return new SyntaxToken(SyntaxKind.BadToken, position++, text.Substring(position - 1, 1), null);
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you try compiling it first?